# Django rest framework overwriting initial for custom logging bypasses OAuth initialisation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm sure there must be something I don't understand about type hierarchies and initialisation in python...
I wanted to log post bodies with django rest framework like suggested [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578946/logging-requests-to-django-rest-framework): by overriding initial and finalize_response.

This is how my mixin looks like:

```
class LoggingMixin(object):
"""
Provides full logging of requests and responses
"""

def finalize_response(self, request, response, *args, **kwargs):
    # do the logging
    if settings.DEBUG:
        logger.debug("[{0}] {1}".format(self.__class__.__name__, response.data))
    return super(LoggingMixin, self).finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)

def initial(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # do the logging
    if settings.DEBUG:
        try:
            data = request._data
            logger.debug("[{0}] {1}".format(self.__class__.__name__, data))
        except exceptions.ParseError:
            data = '[Invalid data in request]'

    super(LoggingMixin, self).initial(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

And my view:

```
class BulkScan(LoggingMixin, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
"""
Provides get (list all) and post (single) for scans.
"""
queryset = Scan.objects.all()
serializer_class = ScanSerializer
authentication_classes = (OAuth2Authentication,)
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

# insert the user on save
def pre_save(self, obj):
    for scan in obj:
        scan.user = self.request.user

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = ScanSerializer(data=request.DATA, many=True)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        self.pre_save(serializer.object)
        self.object = serializer.save(force_insert=True)
        self.post_save(self.object, created=True)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                        headers=headers)

    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Yet, a post or get request fails, complaining that the request.user property is not present. This must automagically be injected there. If I don't overwrite `initial` then everything is fine and the user is set when `APIView.initial` is called.

For now, I resorted to overriding `get` and `post` and then logging the content of the post body but I don't get why the user property is not set when I override the method.

Many thanks for any clarification on this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the super implementation of initial wrong. Don't pass `self`:

```
super(LoggingMixin, self).initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Hopefully that fixes it — there doesn't seem to be anything else wrong.

Comment: Sadly not. This complains that `super(LoggingMixin).initial(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'initial'`

Comment: Erm... I meant don't pass self to `initial`. (See the code in answer.)

Answer (score 0):

@carlton-gibson is correct, but there's one other thing. I had this same issue. Fixed it by calling the super()'s `initial()` before doing the logging.

```
def initial(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # do the logging
    result = super(LoggingMixin, self).initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
    if settings.DEBUG:
        try:
            data = request._data
            logger.debug("[{0}] {1}".format(self.__class__.__name__, data))
        except exceptions.ParseError:
            data = '[Invalid data in request]'
    return result
```