# Django + rest framework - url tracking

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to keep track of url hit count daily in a db and was wondering what would be the best tool do so? I'm running nginx, django, and django rest framework.

edit:
the main goal is not only to track a given url but the parameters passed in. I have an object building and an object person. People belong to a building. You pass in a building id (GET using url) and receive all the people for that building. I'm wanting to be able to see total url calls to buildings and get a count for each particular building.

Comment: Why not let that to an analytics engine instead of Django?

Comment: I want to be able to track routes and the attributes passed in these routes. I think with web analytics you'll get urls but not the variables? I think I left that out the original question so I'll add that in.

Comment: Hey OP, did you figure out an answer to this? Thanks.

Comment: @pyramidface I ended up using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578946/logging-requests-to-django-rest-framework/27928365#27928365 as middleware and I'm logging the results to a log file.

Answer (score 1):

One tool I've found is [`drf-tracking`](https://github.com/aschn/drf-tracking). Seems to track what you want through the addition of a simple mixin on your view.

Comment: drf-tracking I think is a great candidate but at the time of this writing it has gone stale with little activity from the repo owner to keep it up date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) to keep track on the number of clicks/users per day.

Otherwise if you are looking for a Django specific plugin/app, you can try using [django-analytics](https://github.com/jcassee/django-analytical)

Comment: Users aren't loading HTML in this example. It's a REST API serving JSON/XML/etc.