# Name of view inside decorator_from_middleware class

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

While using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578946/logging-requests-to-django-rest-framework) implementation for logging events by view I came across the need to get the name of the view. How do you do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the resolved url from the request object

```
request.resolver_match.view_name
```