# Django Rest Framework debug post and put requests

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-debug-toolbar

I use DRF extension to se json list for model, and there i can debug with `debug-toolbar` that `GET` request, but how can i debug `POST` and `PUT` requests?

I have this for settings in debug mode:

```
INSTALLED_APPS += ('debug_toolbar',)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += ('debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',)

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PATCH_SETTINGS = False
INTERNAL_IPS = (
    '127.0.0.1'
)
```

Now, when i try with `Intercept redirects` in debug-toolbar, it doesn't show me toolbar when i do `POST`.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118183/how-to-debug-in-django-the-good-wayand personally when I work with api's the best way to debug/code is by writing tests

Answer (score 5):

If you need to intercept the request/response and apply your own processing then you can add your custom mixin as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27928365).

But in the most trivial scenario, given that you do a test POST request (or PUT), for example, with python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/):

```py
import requests
response = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/person', json={"name": "dinsdale"})
```

Then you can get the error message with

```py
print(response.text)
```

In most cases the output will contain the failure reason that you were looking for, e.g. `'age' is required`.

You can also do the same thing with `curl` from a terminal:

```bash
curl -vv --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --request POST \
    --data '{"name":"dinsdale"}' http://localhost:8000/person/
```

Answer (score 3):

When debugging interactively on a local machine, I like to examine the `request` data by breaking in the relevant `put()` or `post()` method in `rest_framework.generics`.

For quick local debugging of `POST` or `PUT` validation errors (e.g. in case of http status 400 issues), I like to break at the end of `Field.run_validators()` in `rest_framework.fields` and examine the error messages there.

Answer (score 0):

You can not intercept redirects in DRF browsable api because it is ajax and called via javascript. Also the toolbar is not shown because of ajax call. As workaround you could temporary comment lines in `debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware#process_request` that disables toolbar in ajax call:

```
    ...
    # Don't render the toolbar during AJAX requests.
    # if request.is_ajax():
    #     return
    ...
```

Redirects still would not work, but toolbar would be visible.