# How to log api calls into databse using django?

Tags: django

I don't know how to log all the API calls like API name, API call time, API call success/fail status into my sqlite3 database. Please help me I have no idea about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578946/logging-requests-to-django-rest-framework). It creates a middleware which is a layer that interacts with every incoming request and every returning response. It can be used to perform certain action for incoming request - in this case save request details to the database.